# Locking in python does not behave like expected

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, locking

I have this code:

```
SP500 = pd.read_csv("http://trading.chrisconlan.com/SPstocks_current.csv", header=-1, names=['Symbol']).copy()
SP500=list(SP500.Symbol)
SP500=['AVGO', 'GM', 'FDX', 'goog']

threads = []
lock = threading.Lock()
offset = 1
multiply = 1
num_of_threads = 4
for i in range(0, num_of_threads):
    t = threading.Thread(target=digest_distros, args=(SP500, i * multiply, i * multiply + offset))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

This is the func

```
def digest_distros(SPT500, start, finish):
    for stock in SP500[start:finish]:

        daily, stock_distro = get_daily_adjusted(stock)
        if daily is None:
            continue
        monthly_adjusted_close=get_monthly_adjusted(stock)
        if monthly_adjusted_close is None:
            continue

        with lock:
            print "\n"
            print "##############   " + stock + "   ##############"
            print daily[['low', 'high', 'open', 'adjusted close']].tail(1)
            print "\n"

            curr_monthly_adjusted=monthly_adjusted_close[-1]
            print "##########################"
            print "current monthly adjusted close is: {}".format(curr_monthly_adjusted)
            required_value_for_signal=find_min_signal_value(monthly_adjusted_close)
            print "Required value for signal tommorow is : {}".format(required_value_for_signal)
            print "##########################"

            print "\n"

            spans = [0.3, 0.5, 1, 2,3,5]
            for span in spans:
                mean=stock_distro[span][0]
                std=stock_distro[span][1]
                if abs(curr_monthly_adjusted-required_value_for_signal) < 3:
                    print "Time span is {:.3f} years, daily change mean {:.3f}, daily change std {:.3f}".format(span,mean,std)
                    z_value=calculate_z_value(required_value_for_signal, curr_monthly_adjusted, mean, std)
                    # if z_value>0.3:
                    print "Probability is: {:.3f}".format(z_value)
```

When running, if the code reaches the code inside the for loop or inside the if statement (I think), I lose my lock...

Can't understand why.

Example output for mixed printing.

########   GM

#

current monthly adjusted close is: 37.64
Required value for signal tommorow is : 38.5

#

Time span is 0.300 years, daily change mean -0.083, daily change std 0.692
Probability is: 0.869
Time span is 0.500 years, daily change mean 0.004, daily change std 0.663
Probability is: 0.904
Time span is 1.000 years, daily change mean 0.009, daily change std 0.531
Probability is: 0.949

Time span is 2.000 years, daily change mean 0.018, daily change std 0.512##############   AVGO   ##############

Probability is: 0.957
Time span is 3.000 years, daily change mean 0.005, daily change std 0.495
Probability is: 0.960
Time span is 5.000 years, daily change mean 0.011, daily change std 0.477
Probability is: 0.966

Comment: If you run this with unbuffered stdout (the `-u` flag on the command line), is the output still interleaved? Or, alternatively, if you add an explicit `flush` after the `for` loop, is the output still interleaved? If the answer to either one is no, you don't actually have any problem with locking; you just have unflushed writes when you give up the lock.

Comment: Im running this in jupyter. how do I "inject" the commands you are talking about?

Comment: To inject the `flush`, just edit your source code to add `sys.stdout.flush()` at the end of the `with` block (still indented within it, but after the rest of the code). To inject the `-u`… I'm not sure. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534440/passing-command-line-arguments-to-argv-in-jupyter-ipython-notebook), but you'd think there must be an easier way? Alternatively, you can search SO for how to programmatically switch `sys.stdout` to an unbuffered stream and edit your source—much less ideal, but maybe a usable fallback if needed?

Comment: why is it so complicated? isnt LOCK suppose to work out of the box for the whole block?

Comment: Lock doesn’t lock every file, stream, etc. in the universe and force them all to flush their buffers. That would be terrible.

Comment: Looks like the std flush did it. I didn't do the other thing. Can you explain what exactly in the code is not locked? Why is it not working only at the end for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest fix to get what you want is to flush the output buffers right before you exit the lock. Like this:

```
with lock:
    # ... stuff
    print(stuff)
    # etc.
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Why is this necessary? Because `print` doesn't actually put anything on the terminal. What it does is put something in the `sys.stdout` buffer, so that it will eventually get to the screen. That "eventually" could well be after you've released the lock.

Locking works just fine, and there's nothing in your code that isn't locked; the problem is that locking doesn't force every file—or other buffered type—in the universe to become unbuffered. Think about it this way: if you `send` data over the network from inside a lock, there's no way to guarantee that the other side has received the data by the time you release the lock (except to wait, still holding the lock, for some acknowledgement).