# how to use argument parser in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

https://github.com/ITCoders/Human-detection-and-Tracking/blob/master/main.py
This is the code I obtained for the human detection. I'm using anaconda navigator(jupyter notebook). How can I use argument parser in this? How can I give the video path *-v* ? Can anyone please say me a solution for this? As the running of the program is done by clicking on the run button or by giving *shift+Enter*. I need to do human detection. I'm a beginner to python and opencv. So please do help.

Comment: You should put your code here, as part of your question, and provide a minimal; reproductible example of your issue

Comment: I would just create a new Jupyter cell where I'd define the values I'd give as arguments. You can put those values in the `args` dict directly, and then call whatever function uses it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing command line arguments to argv in jupyter/ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534440/passing-command-line-arguments-to-argv-in-jupyter-ipython-notebook)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking seems similar to: [Passing command line arguments to argv in jupyter/ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534440/passing-command-line-arguments-to-argv-in-jupyter-ipython-notebook)

There are two different methods mentioned in the post that were helpful. That said, I would suggest using command line tools and a Python IDE for writing scripts to run machine learning models. IPython may be helpful for visualization, fast debugging or running pre-trained models on commonly available datasets.

Answer (score 13):

**All for me to do was pass an empty string to parser.parse_args()**

`parser.parse_args()  >   parser.parse_args("")`

**And that was all for me.**

Comment: After trying many things, this answer worked for me. I just want to know the explanation behind it. Are we overriding the **sys.argv** for the **argparse** instance?

Answer (score 2):

I tried out the answers listed on "[Passing command line arguments to argv in jupyter/ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534440/passing-command-line-arguments-to-argv-in-jupyter-ipython-notebook)", and came up with a different solution.

My original code was

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True, help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-y", "--yolo", required=True, help="base path to YOLO directory")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.5, help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
ap.add_argument("-t", "--threshold", type=float, default=0.3, help="threshold when applying non-maxima suppression")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

The most common solution was to create a dummy class, which I wrote as:

```
Class Args():
    image='photo.jpg'
    yolo='yolo-coco'
    confidence=0.5
    threshold=0.3

args=Args()
```

but futher code snippets were producing an error.

So I printed `args` after `vars(ap.parse_args())` and found that it was a dictionary.

So just create a dictionary for the original args:

```
args={"image":  'photo.jpg', "yolo":  'yolo-coco', "confidence": 0.5,"threshold": 0.3}
```