# How to call a main function with parameter in colab

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

Hi Im passing my codes to colab. 
And its runing on my PC, but when I pass it for colab it shows an error...

I'm calling the function in my PC like this:

```
python3 pythonFile.py x
```

Where the x is a number.

but when I run the code, it gives an error when I call:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-f'
```

In the and of main script I have the following code

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thanks  a lot

Comment: can you provide the code ?

Comment: The answser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534440/passing-command-line-arguments-to-argv-in-jupyter-ipython-notebook