# Convert python script to Jupyter and save the output in html

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, papermill

I have a python script, which takes `--days` params and outputs graphs for the range, i want to convert this python script to Jupyter notebook and execute the code and save the output in html format.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
     "--days",
     type=int,
     default=1,
     help="Specify number of days data needed, else defaults to 1 day",
    )
args = parser.parse_args()
```

above lines gets saved in a Jupyter cell on conversion, how do pass the days argument while executing the jupyter notebook ?

Used papermill for execution and ran into the below error:

```
Output Notebook: mynotebook_output.ipynb
Executing:   0%|                                                                                     | 0/13 [00:00<?, ?cell/s]Executing notebook with kernel: python3
Executing:  15%|███████████▊                                                                 | 2/13 [00:01<00:09,  1.17cell/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/sanju/.local/bin/papermill", line 8, in <module>
   sys.exit(papermill())
File "/home/sanju/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/sanju/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
   rv = self.invoke(ctx)
File "/home/sanju/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
   return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
File "/home/sanju/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
   return callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/sanju/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/papermill/cli.py", line 238, in papermill
   execution_timeout=execution_timeout,
File "/home/sanju/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/papermill/execute.py", line 110, in execute_notebook
   raise_for_execution_errors(nb, output_path)
File "/home/sanju/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/papermill/execute.py", line 222, in raise_for_execution_errors
   raise error 
   papermill.exceptions.PapermillExecutionError:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception encountered at "In [2]":
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
    
SystemExit: 2
```

Also tried running the python script as cmd line on the jupyter notebook, the python script executed but no graphs are shown.
[image: jupyter nb]
Do advice if its the right path or is there a better version to convert the python script with output graphs in a html version.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for<br>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534440/passing-command-line-arguments-to-argv-in-jupyter-ipython-notebook

Comment: @SaurabhBadenkal I did see that, its cumbersome, will keep that as my last option, i do not want to make major changes to the existing code.