# Error in argparse when running the code using jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm following a data-flair tutorial and everything is working well except when it comes to this:

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument('-i', '--image', required=True, help="Image Path")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
img_path = args['image']
```

it gives me this error,

[image: error]

I tried writing the code in text file then save it as .py file but it gives the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing command line arguments to argv in jupyter/ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534440/passing-command-line-arguments-to-argv-in-jupyter-ipython-notebook)

Comment: remove `'-i,'`  as it is not necessary

Comment: Prakash Dahal, I tried it before but the same error occurred.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not comment).

Comment: if you follow some tutorial then add link to this tutorial - put it in question, not comment.

Comment: create minimal working code with this problem and show how you run it. Do it in question, not in comment. Did you run it as `python script.py -i some_image` in console/terminal?

Comment: @furas I run it as !python example.py from jupyter notebook

Comment: then you have to run it as `!python example.py -i some_image`. OR remove all `argparse` and assign image directly in code `img_path = "some_image"`

Comment: I want the image to be passed to the model then the caption for that image to be generated by the model to be displayed on command line. @furas

Comment: then you have to run it as `!python example.py -i some_image`

Comment: @furas  I run `!python ex1212.py -i --image` but same error occurred `error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image`

Comment: you have to use `-i` OR `--image` with `filename` - like `!python example.py -i lenna.png` or `!python example.py --image lenna.png`.  Or even better with full path like `!python example.py -i /home/furas/images/lenna.png`

Comment: @furas so I should also use the path here `ap.add_argument('-i', '--image', required=True, help="Image Path")` ? in the `help="Image Path"`

Comment: NO, don't change `args` - it is correct. It will automatically create variable `ap.image` with value `/home/furas/images/lenna.png` (or with any string you use after `--image` in command line)

Comment: BTW: instead of two lines `args = vars(ap.parse_args())` and `img_path = args['image']` you can directy use `img_path = ap.image`

Comment: and `help` is only to display information when you use it with `-h` or `--help` like  `!python example.py --help`

Answer (score 0):

Code is OK but you run it incorrectly.

You should run it with `-i` or `--image` and with `image's filename` or with `/full/path/to/image`

```
!python example.py -i lenna.png

!python example.py --image lenna.png

!python example.py -i /home/furas/images/lenna.png

!python example.py --image /home/furas/images/lenna.png
```

---

And `help=" "` is only to display information when you run it as

```
!python example.py --help
```

or shorter

```
!python example.py -h
```

Result:

```
usage: example.py [-h] -i INPUT

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -i INPUT, --input INPUT
                        Image Path
```

In second column it shows `Image Path` which was in `help="Image Path"`.

You can change it to something more readable like `help="put path to image"` and you get

```
usage: example.py [-h] -i INPUT

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -i INPUT, --input INPUT
                        put path to image
```

---

Brackets `[]` in `[-h]` means that `-h` is optional.

`-i INPUT` means that it is required and it needs some value in place of `INPUT`.

It also shows that you can use:

- `--help` instead of `-h`
- `--image` instead of `-i`

---

**BTW:**

Instead of two lines

```
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
img_path = args['image']
```

you can run directly

```
img_path = ap.image
```

Comment: Now, I changed the argparse to `ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument('--image', required=True, help="Image Path")
img_path = 'ap.image'`  and I run at as `!python ex1212.py --image 42637986_135a9786a6.jpg` but it gives me this error `NameError: name 'load' is not defined` from this code `max_length = 32
tokenizer = load(open("tokenizer.p","rb"))
model = load_model('models/model_9.h5')`

Comment: it shows that `argparse` works correctly (so this problem is resolved) but now you have totally different problem in different place and you should have to create new question on new page. You use some `load()` which you should have to define or `import` from other file - so better check if you have `def load()` in some place in tutorial. And when you create new question on new page then better add link to your tutorial.