# How to run a jupyter notebook cell in VS code with command line arguments (staying in the notebook context)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way running a jupyter notebook python cell with command line parameters retaining the whole variable visibility of a notebook?

What I tried:

- According to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534440/passing-command-line-arguments-to-argv-in-jupyter-ipython-notebook?answertab=modifieddesc#tab-top) I prefixed my script with `%%python - --option1 value1 - -option2 value2 - -etc` but this only runs it as a normal python script. No variables visible, no notebook interaction.
- [papermill](https://github.com/nteract/papermill) adresses this issue but relies on tags not available in VS code.
- export as normal py script ... of course this works but is cumbersome in the development process
- hardcoding default values in argpare ... but again this is an ugly way as I keep altering code which shouldn't be changed when debugging.

I'm aware of [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534440/passing-command-line-arguments-to-argv-in-jupyter-ipython-notebook) also not coming to a clean general solution.